# Long delays displaying UIImageView loaded from local file?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, nskeyedunarchiver

I see questions regarding long delays in displaying UIImageViews after downloading, but my question involves long delays when
reading from local storage.

After archiving my hierarchy of UIImageViews to a local file (as per narohi's answer in 
[How to output a view hierarchy & contents to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160972/how-to-output-a-view-hierarchy-contents-to-file/32161942#32161942) ),
I find that if I want to reload them, it takes 5 to 20 seconds for the views to actually appear on screen,
despite my setting setNeedsDiplay() on the main view and all the subviews.

I can immediately query the data contained in the 
custom subclasses of UIView that get loaded -- showing that NSKeyedUnarchiver and all the NS-decoding and all the init()'s have completed -- however 
the images just don't appear on the screen for a long time.  Surely the next redraw cycle is shorter than 5-20 seconds...?

It seems odd that images from PhotoLibrary appear instantly, but anything loaded from local file storage using NSKeyedUnarchiver takes "forever."

What's going on here, and how can I speed this up?

.

.

To be explicit, the relevant part of my Swift code looks like this:

```
let view = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(path) as! UIView!
if (nil == view) {
   return
}
myMainView.addSubview(view)
view.setNeedsDisplay()
// now do things with the data in view ...which all works fine
```

I find that, even if I add something like...

```
for subview in view.subviews {
    subview.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

...it doesn't speed up the operations.

We are not talking huge datasets either, it could be just a single imageview that's being reloaded.

Now, I do also notice these delays occurring when downloading from the internet using a downloader like the one shown in
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28221670/4259243
...but I have the downloader print a completion message after not only the download but when the (synchronous operation) 
data.writeToFile() is complete (and before I try to load it using NSKeyedUnarchiver), so this indicates that the delay 
in UIImageView redraws is NOT because the download is still commencing....and like I say, you can query the properties of the data and it's all in memory, just not displaying on the screen.

**UPDATE:**  As per comments, I have enclosed the needsDisplay code in dispatch_async as per Leo Dabus's advice, and done some Time Profiling as per Paulw11's.  Link to Time Profiling results is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLri1.png  I stopped the profiling immediately after the image appeared on the screen at around 1:00, but it was actually 'loaded' during the bump around 20s.  During that period it seems like nothing's happening...?  The code is literally just waiting around for a while?

Just to be clear how I'm implementing the dispatch_async, see here:

```
func addViewToMainView(path: String) {
    let view = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(path) as! UIView!
    if (nil == view) {
       return
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
       self.myMainView.addSubview(view)
       view.setNeedsDisplay()
       self.myMainView.setNeedsDisplay()
    })
}
```

...Since posting this I've found a few posts where people are complaining about how slow NSKeyedUnarchiver is.  Could it just be that?  If so, :-(.

**SECOND UPDATE**: Ahh, the "let view = " needs to be in the dispatch_async.  In fact, if you just put the whole thing in the dispatch_async, it works beautifully!  so...

```
func addViewToMainView(path: String) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        let view = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(path) as! UIView!
        if (nil == view) {
           return
        }

       self.myMainView.addSubview(view)
       view.setNeedsDisplay()
       self.myMainView.setNeedsDisplay()
    })
}
```

This works instantly.  Wow..  Credit to Leo Dabus.   Leaving this here for others...

Comment: You need to update the UI from the main thread. all you need is to use dispatch async from the main queue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27712427/2303865

Comment: Thanks, uh, I must be dense: how is pushing the UI update to asynchronous operation (which seems to be what's happening anyway) supposed to help?   Just as an exercise, I wrapped the addSubview and setNeedsDisplay() in dispatch_async, but it still took 19 seconds to update.   `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { self.myMainView.addSubview(view)
view.setNeedsDisplay()  self.myMainView.setNeedsDisplay() })`   ...No effect.

Comment: You should run your app with the time profiler instruments tool and see where the time is being spent.

Comment: Where do you create your view? Thats where you need to use dispatch async.

Comment: Thanks guys, I updated & added new content to the question to address Time Profiling and show using dispatch_async where I create the view.

Comment: Boom.  Sorry, Leo, I did not understand that the view creation itself needs to be in the dispatch_async.  Now it works immediately!   Thanks!  Will make one final update to show new code.  If you want to make your comment into an answer, I'll pick it!